# Combining multiple sub-queries into a single query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm attempting to combine several sub queries to form a report detailing order in an 'In Progress' status. Long story short there are multiple stages an order goes through and the client wants to get the total inventory in each stage at the unit level.

This is my attempt at combining the first couple two, thoughts were if I was unable to do I wouldn't be able to add the other two.

```
select In_Progress_Total.purchase_order, In_Progress, In_Progress_Awaiting_Vas
from
(   select order_header.purchase_order, move_task.work_group,SUM(move_task.qty_to_move) AS In_Progress
    from move_task
    join order_header
    on move_task.task_id = order_header.order_id
    where move_task.site_id = 'USCOL1' and move_task.client_id = 'SDRY-US' and order_header.status = 'In Progress'
    group by order_header.purchase_order, move_task.work_group); as In_Progress_Total
join
(   select order_header.purchase_order, move_task.work_group, SUM(move_task.qty_to_move) AS In_Progress_Awaiting_Vas
    from move_task
    join order_header
    on move_task.task_id = order_header.order_id
    where move_task.site_id = 'USCOL1' and move_task.client_id = 'SDRY-US' and move_task.from_loc_id like 'DEPT%VAS' and order_header.status = 'In Progress'
    group by order_header.purchase_order, move_task.work_group); as Awaiting_Vas)
on In_Progress_Total.purchase_order = Awaiting_Vas.purchase_order
order by In_Progress_Total.purchase_order
```

When running this two things happen it runs the query as two queries instead of one, I get the following error (which once resolved causes another):

[Multiple Queries / Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHLen.png)

Additional two queries to combine:

```
select order_header.purchase_order, move_task.work_group,SUM(move_task.qty_to_move) AS In_Progress_Awaiting_Labels
from move_task
join order_header
on move_task.task_id = order_header.order_id
where move_task.site_id = 'USCOL1' and move_task.client_id = 'SDRY-US' and move_task.from_loc_id like 'OUTVAS' and order_header.status = 'In Progress'
group by order_header.purchase_order, move_task.work_group


select order_header.purchase_order, move_task.work_group,SUM(move_task.qty_to_move) AS Everything_Else
from move_task
join order_header
on move_task.task_id = order_header.order_id
where move_task.site_id = 'USCOL1' and move_task.client_id = 'SDRY-US' and order_header.status = 'In Progress' and move_task.from_loc_id not like '%OUTVAS%' and move_task.from_loc_id not like 'DEPT%VAS' 
group by order_header.purchase_order, move_task.work_group
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: you can use correlated subquery for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using conditional aggregation where you move `WHERE` conditions into `CASE` statements for the different `SUM` aggregates. Be sure to also use table aliases for readability.

```
SELECT o.purchase_order, m.work_group,
       SUM(CASE 
               WHEN m.site_id = 'USCOL1' AND 
                    m.client_id = 'SDRY-US' AND 
                    o.status = 'In Progress'
               THEN m.qty_to_move
               ELSE NULL
           END) AS In_Progress,

       SUM(CASE 
               WHEN m.site_id = 'USCOL1' AND 
                    m.client_id = 'SDRY-US' AND 
                    m.from_loc_id LIKE 'DEPT%VAS' AND 
                    o.status = 'In Progress'
               THEN m.qty_to_move
               ELSE NULL
           END) AS In_Progress_Awaiting_Vas,

       SUM(CASE
               WHEN m.site_id = 'USCOL1' AND 
                    m.client_id = 'SDRY-US' AND 
                    m.from_loc_id LIKE 'OUTVAS' AND 
                    o.status = 'In Progress'
               THEN m.qty_to_move
               ELSE NULL
           END) AS In_Progress_Awaiting_Labels,

       SUM(CASE
               WHEN m.site_id = 'USCOL1' AND 
                    m.client_id = 'SDRY-US' AND 
                    o.status = 'In Progress' AND 
                    m.from_loc_id NOT LIKE '%OUTVAS%' AND 
                    m.from_loc_id NOT LIKE 'DEPT%VAS'
               THEN m.qty_to_move
               ELSE NULL
           END) AS Everything_Else

FROM move_task m
JOIN order_header o ON m.task_id = o.order_id 
GROUP BY o.purchase_order, m.work_group
```